# Stream groupingBy a list of enum types

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have a Product class:

```
class Product {
    String name;
    List<Group> group;
    //more fields, getters, setters
    public Product(String name, Group... group) {
        this.name = name;
        this.group = Arrays.asList(group);
    }
}
```

where Group is an enum

```
public enum Group {
    LEISURE,
    SPORT,
    FORMALATTIRE,
    BABY,
    MATERNITY
    //...
}
```

From a list of products I want to create a `Map<Group,List<Product>>`

Example input:

```
List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

productList.add(new Product("A", Group.BABY, Group.MATERNITY));
productList.add(new Product("B", Group.BABY, Group.LEISURE, Group.SPORT));
productList.add(new Product("C", Group.SPORT, Group.LEISURE));
productList.add(new Product("D", Group.LEISURE, Group.SPORT, Group.FORMALATTIRE));
productList.add(new Product("E", Group.SPORT, Group.LEISURE));
productList.add(new Product("F", Group.FORMALATTIRE, Group.LEISURE));
```

If group was a single field just like name I could do:

```
productList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName));
```

How can I do it with a `List<Group>` ?

Expected result is something like below, where for each group which exists in the productList a mapping to a list of products having this group in their field `group`

```
{MATERNITY=[A], FORMALATTIRE=[D, F], LEISURE=[B, C, D, E, F], SPORT=[B, C, D, E], BABY=[A, B]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `flatMap` the group within each `Product` to the `name` of the product and then group it by `Group` mapping the corresponding `name`s as value. Such as:

```
Map<Group, List<String>> groupToNameMapping = productList.stream()
        .flatMap(product -> product.getGroup().stream()
                .map(group -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(group, product.getName())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

or to get a mapping of the group to list of product, you can formulate the same as:

```
Map<Group, List<Product>> groupToProductMapping = productList.stream()
        .flatMap(product -> product.getGroup().stream()
                .map(group -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(group, product)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Have tried your approach but getting error incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds lower bounds: Product,T#2,Object lower bounds: String

Comment: @nopens edited the answer. it shall resolve the issue and provide what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second aproach is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a stream of `Entry<Group,String>` by using `flatMap` and then collect them into `Map<Group, List<String>>` using `Collectors.mapping`

```
productList.stream()
               .flatMap(p->p.getGroup()
                            .stream()
                            .map(g->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(g,p.getName())))   // or from jdk 9 you can use Map.entry(g, p.getName());
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                       Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: the type of entry is also inferrable, so one can use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>`

Comment: Have tied your approach but getting error `incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
    lower bounds: Product,T#2,Object
    lower bounds: String`

Comment: Never mind. My fault. I was expecting `Map<Group,List<Product>>`. I've changed p.getName to p and it is working as desiered.