# Sorting by enum parameters items from a list using Java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, groupingby

Lets assume I have a list of walls listOfWalls and that each wall object has following hierarchy:

```
wall -> wallType -> wallEntry(list of wall materials ) -> wallMaterial -> wallMaterialType(enum type),
```

so in order to get wallMaterialType of some wall in this list, I would go like

```
wall.getWallType().getWallEntry().getWallMaterial().getWallMaterialType();
```

Now class Wall has also following params: `width` and `height` which multiplied together gets an area of the wall by calling my function `getWallArea()` from Wall class.

What I would like to achieve is to get area of all wallMaterialTypes from a list of walls calculated, so for instance lets assume we have 2 walls:

1. Wall 1 with following wallMaterialTypes: Brick, Plaster, Wood and wallArea() of 35 sq. meters.
2. Wall 2 with following wallMaterialTypes: Hay, Plaster and wallArea() of 105 square meters.

Now what output I would like to have is:

```
BRICK: 35 square meters.
Plaster: 140 square meters.
Wood: 35 square meters.
Hay: 105 square meters.
```

My code so far is looking something like this where have I pulled for each

```
 Map<WallType, Double> getIt = listOfWalls.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Wall::getWallType, Collectors.summingDouble(Wall::getWallArea)));
```

From there I am clueless how to go? Help appreciated.

Comment: Does `getWallMaterialType` return a `List<WallMaterialType>`?

Comment: Sharing some classes would help to try and not write your code by ourelves ;)

Comment: Please always try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: As far as I see you have the correct map. Do you ask how to print it in this format? Or how to print it within the stream pipeline?

Comment: Related of mostly a duplicate of [Stream groupingBy a list of enum types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475865/stream-groupingby-a-list-of-enum-types/58475946#58475946)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to map by the `WallMaterialType` enum.

```
Map<WallMaterialType, Double> result = walls.stream()
            .flatMap(wall -> wall.getWallType().getWallEntry().getWallMaterials()
                    .stream()
                    .map(wallMaterial -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(wallMaterial.getWallMaterialType(),
                            wall.getWallArea())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                    Collectors.summingDouble(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)));
```

If you keep calling `map(..)` and reach the *WallMaterials*, you would lose the Wall's `wallArea` Hence, I have grouped everything into a single `flatMap` step to return a map (simple pair would do too) of wall material type and the wall's area.

(The `flatMap` step returns a simple mapping of a `WallMaterialType` and the `wallArea` to which the `wallMaterialType` belongs to).

The collect is similar to what you've already written.

Comment: nitpick - `wall.getWallType().getWallEntry().stream()` should be sufficient given `wallEntry` is a list of wall material.

Comment: @user7  I have written edit to your answer for possible further clarification and solution.